# Cypress - How to use browser network information

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

We are developing a system where the login is made with 6 digits that are sent by email. In Dev, we can get these 6 digits, in the 'login' element on the browser network.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uqne.png

The problem is, I'm doing some automated tests with Cypress, and I don't know how to get this info from the browser network to login. It is possible?

Here's an example of the code:

```
describe('login', () => {
        
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('url from the website');
    })

    it('login', () => {
        //just a button to go to the login
        cy.get('.css-90db6r > .chakra-button').click();

        //the field for fill the CPF (like a username) and get the 6 digits in email
        cy.get('#cpf').type('cpfnumber');

        //button to click to go forward and get the 6 digits
        cy.get('.chakra-stack > .chakra-button').click();

        //field to fill with the 6 digits
        cy.get('.css-k008qs > :nth-child(1)').type('6 digits');

    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [`.intercept()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Glob-Pattern-Matching-URLs) with [`.as()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as) to get your 6 digit code from the request.

```js
describe('login', () => {
        
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('url from the website');
    })

    it('login', () => {
        //just a button to go to the login
        cy.get('.css-90db6r > .chakra-button').click();

        //the field for fill the CPF (like a username) and get the 6 digits in email
        cy.get('#cpf').type('cpfnumber');

        // create intercept and give alias
        cy.intercept('login').as('login')

        //button to click to go forward and get the 6 digits
        cy.get('.chakra-stack > .chakra-button').click();

        // wait on request and check it has generatedCode property
        cy.wait('@login')
          .its('response.body')
          .should('have.property', 'generatedCode')
          // enter generatedCode
          .then(sixDigitCode => {
            //field to fill with the 6 digits
            cy.get('.css-k008qs > :nth-child(1)').type(sixDigitCode);
          }
    })

})
```